# Seperable differential equations and a simple problem..

Tags: calculus

Going through the excellent "bridging the gap to university mathematics", I'm stuck on (what appears to be) a simple exercise problem in separable differential equations.

The problem is:
 Solve
    $dy/dx + 1 = y^2$

The book chapter deals with how to use partial fractions to solve this type of problem by "moving the $y$'s to one side of the equation and $x'$s to the other". Clearly I'm missing something in how to re-arrange the equation to put $y$ on the $dy/dx$ side.

The answer is shown as 1/2 ln $|(y-1)/(y+1)| = x + k$

I get the $x$ side (integral of $1 = x +c).$

I don't follow how the $(y-1)/(y+1)$ is obtained. I understand that this is derived from $ln |(y-1)| - ln |(y+1)| ,$ but how the $1/y^2$ is split into partial fractions (with $1/(y-1) - 1/y+1)$ I can't work out.

Sorry for formatting…

Any help on how to rearrange and split into partial fractions really appreciated. I know I need to divide LHS by $y^2$ but I can't get the same answer.

Many thanks.
Col.

Comment: do you know how to separate the variables?

Comment: $y^{2}-1 = (y-1)(y+1)$

Comment: Hi, many thanks for coming back to me. Yes I see what solution is now. I was diving by y^2 on both sides rather than subtracting 1 from both sides first. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first write the differential equation as $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = y^2 -1$

(a)  now move all the $y$'s to one side like $\dfrac{dy}{y^2 -1} = dx $

(b) determine the constants $A$ and $B$ so that $\dfrac{1}{y^2 - 1} = 
\dfrac{A}{y-1} + \dfrac{B}{y+1}$

(c) use the fact $\int \dfrac{dy}{ay+b} = \dfrac{1}{a}\ln |ay + b|$

Comment: @TZakrevskiy, thanks for spotting the error.

Comment: Many thanks Abel!